# CAML Query Issue A or B and C

Tags: caml-query, caml

I'm trying to write a CAML query with the following parameters and I'm not having much luck.
It should be simple enough but I can't figure it out.

WHERE (X) EQUALS (A or B) And C

I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write query like below:

```
<Where>
   <And>
      <Or>
         <Eq><FieldRef Name="X" /><Value Type="Text">A</Value></Eq>
         <Eq><FieldRef Name="X" /><Value Type="Text">B</Value></Eq>
     </Or>
     <Eq><FieldRef Name="X" /><Value Type="Text">C</Value></Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

Also, try using some CAML Query Builders that will help you:
[CAML Query Tools suggested by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648040.aspx)
[Caml Query Helper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/)
[U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx)

Comment: You beat my answer out by 40 seconds lol. So close. So close.

Comment: Thank you for the help once again. It's much appreciated.

Comment: @rjcup3 you gotta be fast next time brother :P...

Comment: @E7AD here to help my friend!

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure you want will be something like:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Or>
            <Eq>
                A
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                B
            </Eq>
         </Or>
         <Eq>
             C
         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

A, B, and C will each be a `<FieldRef />` and `<Value></Value>` set.

Hope that makes sense.

## Edit

As Arsalan suggested, Karine Bosch's U2U Caml Builder for 2003 and 2007 is available [here](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx). It makes building the structure of more complex queries a lot easier.

To use it with SP 2010 (unsure about 2013) you can connect via web services as seen [here](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/u2u-caml-query-builder-for-sharepoint.html).